# How to create multiauth in laravel with a single login form

Tags: laravel, authentication

I'm new in laravel. I want to create a multiauth in laravel with a single login form. For User and Admin. Can anybody help me please :)

Comment: Refer this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50515405/10762841
It may help you

Answer (score 0):

1. you can simply copy user Model to a new auth Model class (in this case Admin)
2. create a new guard let say (admin) and map it to Admin Model with the correct namespace.
3. in your project, 
   to get authenticated user `use auth()->user();` // uses the default guard
   to get admin user use `auth()->guard('admin')->user();`